# Emacs 29.1: read-string prompt bug?

Tags: minibuffer, prompt, read-string

I have this example function:

```el
(defun my-test ()
  (interactive)
  (read-string "Very\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nvery\nlong-prompt: "))
```

In previous versions of `Emacs` (I was using `Emacs 26`), I could scroll through the prompt text using the arrow keys. Now, however, in the minibuffer, the arrow keys insert strings from the history and no longer allow me to scroll through the prompt text. I believe this is a bug. Am I mistaken?

**Emacs 29.1**
[image]

**Emacs 26.3**

[image]

Comment: I would say this is a feature. Why would you want to scroll through such a cumbersome prompt? If you prefer the old behavior then you can just rebind the arrow key `(define-key minibuffer-mode-map (kbd "<up>") 'previous-line)`.

Comment: @dalanicolai Sometimes, when I build functions, I use `(read-string (format "%s" VARIABLE))` to check what's going on in some point. Sometimes `VARIABLE` may be a string very long... I know this is not the "professional" way to do it but I find it very useful.

Comment: Ah, sounds clever. There are probably handier ways provided by the debugger, but it's a nice hack. So then just rebind those keys...

Comment: ... or use `C-p`/`C-n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of a deliberate change made in emacs-28 to fix bug [46033](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=46033)

As @NickD suggested, <kbd>C-p</kbd> and <kbd>C-n</kbd> still work.